# How to set the "file version" field in PE header of EXE files?

Tags: go, portable-executable

I use `go build` to build a `exe` file.Then i view the property of the file(Right click the file -> property),In `detail` tab,the file's version is empty.

How i to set the version of the `exe` file.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The EXE file version and other info are embedded as resources, which are specific to Windows and thus not supported by the Go compiler. You can use [the package GoVersionInfo](https://github.com/josephspurrier/goversioninfo) to accomplish this (it also supports embedding an icon). I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising and well documented.

Answer (score 3):

There is [go-winres](https://github.com/tc-hib/go-winres) which lets you do this, either before or after `go build`.

Run `go install github.com/tc-hib/go-winres@latest` to install it.
Then, inside your project folder, run `go-winres init`. This creates a subfolder named `winres`.

Modify `winres/winres.json`, and replace the icon.

Run `go-winres make`. This creates a `.syso` file.
Run `go build` and see the result.

If you want to add a language, there's an example in the readme file. I didn't manage to do it with `goversioninfo`, while it works with `go-winres`.